# Alinhar button ao centro não funciona

Tags: css3

tenho a página abaixo,

http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/gasmuriae

No lado direito da página **index.php**, tem um `botão` peça seu gás.

Ao **clicar**, vai aparecer um `formulário` para preencher dados de endereço.

Ao final dos `form`, tem um `button` que desejo **centralizar**.

Mas nada que faço funciona.

Já coloquei:

```
  margin: auto !important;
  text_align: ceter !important;
```

Nada funciona.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

img {
 border: 0;
 max-width: 100%;
}

label {
 line-height: 40px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

select {
 width: 110px;
 height: 50px;
}

.typeTextGrande, .typeTextMedio, .typeTextPequeno {
 height: 36px;
 padding: 9px;
}

.typeTextPequeno {
 width: 150px;
}

.typeTextMedio {
 width: 250px;
}

.typeTextGrande {
 width: 450px;
}

.labelPequeno {
 width: 100px;
}

.labelMedio {
 width: 200px;
}

.labelGrande {
 width: 300px;
}

.h1Centralizado, .h1CentralizadoAvisos {
 width: 100%;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
}

button.btnPecaGas {
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: right;
 width: 208px;
 height: 44px;
}


button.btnPecaGas {
 background-image: url(../../_img/botijao.png);
}



div.sessoes {
 width:1000px;
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
}

.encomende {
 cursor:pointer;
}

div.pecaGas {
 width:40px;
 background-color: rgb (255,0,0); 
 z-index:10;
}

div.pecaGas div.gas {
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0; 
}

div.peca {
    position: relative;
 display:block;
 width:420px;
 top:calc(50% - 270px);
 right:0; 
 background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
 border: .5px rgb(255,0,0) solid; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
   -moz-border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
    border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px; 
 z-index:10;   
 padding:20px 0 20px 20px;
}

div.peca input, div.peca select {
 width: 250px  !important;;
 border: 1px rgb(255,0,0) solid;
}

div.peca button.fechaPeca {
 position:absolute;
 top:20px;
 right:20px;
 background-color:transparent !important;
}

div.peca button.btnPecaGas {
 margin:auto  !important;
 text-align:center !important;
}

div.peca .labelPequeno {
 width:120px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="peca">
  <button class="fechaPeca"><img src="_img/btn-close.png" /></button>
  <h1 class="h1Centralizado">Peça suas botijas</h1>
  <label for="nomePeca" class="labelPequeno">Nome</label>
  <input type="text" name="nomePeca" id="nomePeca" class="typeTextPequeno" placeholder="Nome"  required />
  <br />
  <br />
  <label for="enderecoPeca" class="labelPequeno">Endereço</label>
  <input type="text" name="enderecoPeca" id="enderecoPeca" class="typeTextPequeno" placeholder="Endereço completo" required  />
  <br />
  <br />
  <label for="bairroPeca" class="labelPequeno">Bairro</label>
  <select name="bairroPeca" class="typeTextPequeno" required>
    <option value="">Selecione o bairro</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <br />
  <label for="telefonePeca" class="labelPequeno">Telefone</label>
  <input type="text" name="telefonePeca" id="telefonePeca" class="typeTextPequeno" placeholder="Telefone"  />
  <br />
  <br />
  <label for="quantidadePeca" class="labelPequeno">Quantas botijas?</label>
  <input type="text" name="quantidadePeca" id="quantidadePeca" class="typeTextPequeno" placeholder="Quantas Botijas"  />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button class="btnPecaGas">Peça já o seu</button>
</div>
```

Onde será que estou errando?

Comment: Acho que isso resolve: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/centraliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-bot%C3%A3o-incorreta/252419#252419

Comment: você pode explicar o porque dessa falha?

Comment: Pode ser muitos fatores... depende muito do CSS envolvido no contexto... outra coisa, geralmente um `margin: 0 auto;` funciona com `display: block;` sem `float: left;`.

Comment: ah tá, você não chegou a ver o código do link que passei não. Foi por  inferência.. Mas valeu. Vou observar! Só passei o link pois poder haver algum conflito de CSS que eu não estou conseguindo enxergar.

Comment: Cheguei a ver, mas agora não abre mais.

Comment: @CarlosRocha como seu link não funcionou fiz uma resposta genérica centralizando o conteúdo em uma `div` usando flex-box.

Comment: Aqui para mim deu normal. talves seja que na hora que voce tentou eu ainda estivesse upando

Comment: Adicionei à pergunta o código que estou usando.

Comment: Editei a resposta e ao final adicionei o seu código com os ajustes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize [`Flex-Box`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), para organizar o layout, no caso eu usei apenas 3 linhas para centralizar o botão.

> **Iniciar flex** - `display: flex`;

```
display: flex; // para startar o flex
```

> **align-items**: [flex-start] [flex-end] [center] [stretch]

```
align-items: center; //para alinhar ao centro
```

> **justify-content**: [flex-start] [flex-end] [center] [space-between] [space-around] [space-evenly]

```
justify-content: center; //para justificar o conteúdo
```

```css
.component {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.btn {
  width: 80px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #27ae60;  
  color: white;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
```

```html
<div class="component">
    <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

#### Abaixo reeditei seu código adicionando o `flex-box` para isso coloquei o `button` em uma `div` com a `class="btn"`  e na classe `btn` adicionei o `flex-box`

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

img {
 border: 0;
 max-width: 100%;
}

label {
 line-height: 40px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

select {
 width: 110px;
 height: 50px;
}

.typeTextGrande, .typeTextMedio, .typeTextPequeno {
 height: 36px;
 padding: 9px;
}

.typeTextPequeno {
 width: 150px;
}

.typeTextMedio {
 width: 250px;
}

.typeTextGrande {
 width: 450px;
}

.labelPequeno {
 width: 100px;
}

.labelMedio {
 width: 200px;
}

.labelGrande {
 width: 300px;
}

.h1Centralizado, .h1CentralizadoAvisos {
 width: 100%;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
}

button.btnPecaGas {
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: right;
 width: 208px;
 height: 44px;
}


button.btnPecaGas {
 background-image: url(../../_img/botijao.png);
}



div.sessoes {
 width:1000px;
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
}

.encomende {
 cursor:pointer;
}

div.pecaGas {
 width:40px;
 background-color: rgb (255,0,0); 
 z-index:10;
}

div.pecaGas div.gas {
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0; 
}

div.peca {
 display:block;
 width:420px;
 top:calc(50% - 270px);
 right:0; 
 background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
 border: .5px rgb(255,0,0) solid; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
   -moz-border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
    border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px; 
 z-index:10;   
 padding:20px 0 20px 20px;
}

div.peca input, div.peca select {
 width: 250px  !important;;
 border: 1px rgb(255,0,0) solid;
}

div.peca button.fechaPeca {
 position:absolute;
 top:20px;
 right:20px;
 background-color:transparent !important;
}

div.peca button.btnPecaGas {
 margin:auto  !important;
 text-align:center !important;
}

div.peca .labelPequeno {
 width:120px !important;
}

.btn{
display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="peca">
  <button class="fechaPeca"><img src="_img/btn-close.png" /></button>
  <h1 class="h1Centralizado">Peça suas botijas</h1>
  <label for="nomePeca" class="labelPequeno">Nome</label>
  <input type="text" name="nomePeca" id="nomePeca" class="typeTextPequeno" placeholder="Nome"  required />
  <br />
  <br />
  <label for="enderecoPeca" class="labelPequeno">Endereço</label>
  <input type="text" name="enderecoPeca" id="enderecoPeca" class="typeTextPequeno" placeholder="Endereço completo" required  />
  <br />
  <br />
  <label for="bairroPeca" class="labelPequeno">Bairro</label>
  <select name="bairroPeca" class="typeTextPequeno" required>
    <option value="">Selecione o bairro</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <br />
  <label for="telefonePeca" class="labelPequeno">Telefone</label>
  <input type="text" name="telefonePeca" id="telefonePeca" class="typeTextPequeno" placeholder="Telefone"  />
  <br />
  <br />
  <label for="quantidadePeca" class="labelPequeno">Quantas botijas?</label>
  <input type="text" name="quantidadePeca" id="quantidadePeca" class="typeTextPequeno" placeholder="Quantas Botijas"  />
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="btn">
  <button class="btnPecaGas">Peça já o seu</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Só para ter certeza: Você apenas colocou o botão dentro de uma div.btn e estilizou ela com display: flex mantendo o reto do código intácto?

Comment: Sim isto mesmo @CarlosRocha, se você ler a documentação tenho certeza que começará a usar `flex-box`

Comment: mas existe alguma explicação para margin auto e text-align: center não funcionarem? Text-align tudo bem pois é um botão mas margin: auto

Comment: Tem várias coisas que podem fazer o margin: 0 auto não funcionarem, pode haver um reset no css principal `*{ ...  }` que reseta o que está entre `{ }` em todos os elementos, ou pode ser que exista outra chamada da mesma classe que já define o margin com outros valores e sub-escrevem o anterior, no seu css tem muitas chamadas ao elemento `div` tente apenas chamar a classe do elemento e a subclasse que deseja subscrever.

Comment: E fique tranquilo para usar `flex-box` o mesmo é nativo do `css3` não é um plugin como já vi algumas pessoas comentarem.

Comment: Deu certo, Resolveu o seu problema?

Comment: Sim, mas poso ser um pouco chato? Será que tem como você tentar explicar por que o botão não quer centralizar da forma que eu fiz sendo que é a forma padrão?

Comment: @CarlosRocha, coloquei seu código no jsfiddle, e verifiquei que falatava inserir `text-align` na classe `peca` e mudei o `padding` para 20px em ambos os lados para que pudesse ser centralizado, [veja seu código aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=kRRcievOBk), mas considere ver sobre o `flex-box`

Comment: Sim, mas o que eu gostaria é que somente o botão fosse centralizado. O form não!